# JavaScript display multiple error message form submission?

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong in my JavaScript?  I would like to display an error message if a user forgets to type in any of my HTML form fields.  I would like to create an error message for the name, email, and phone number fields.  Even if a user puts in their name, I would like error messages for the remainder 2, or remainder 1, or no error messages.  I have attached my JavaScript code below.  Thank you for those who help.

```
function validateForm() {
  var ret = true;
  var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
  if (name == "") {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
    ret = false;
  }
  var email = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
  if (email == "") {
    document.getElementById('erroremail').innerHTML = "Please enter your email";
    ret = false;
  }

  var phone = document.forms["contactform"]["phone"].value;
  if (phone == "") {
    document.getElementById('errorphone').innerHTML = "Please enter your phone";
    ret = false;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want separate error display for each input you could just add `else` with empty `innerHTML`.

Something like this:

```
var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
var nameError = document.getElementById('error');
if (name == "") {
  nameError.innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
  ret = false;
} else {
  nameError.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1h1tkh7y/

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but I am 2 days into JavaScript.  Can you tell me what I can do to my original code?  If I take out the codes for the 'phone', it works for my name and email fields, but after adding the bottom parts for the phone, my code no longer works.

Comment: My example on jsfiddle is same as your original code except I added `else` for each input. Did you try it on jsfiddle and is it working like you wanted there?

Comment: I did try and wasn't working, but I think it may be because my HTML is different than yours.  I will try again.  I have <div> instead of <spans>.

Comment: share your html also if you can't figure it out

Comment: everything works fine there with my code, check it https://jsfiddle.net/eunL38zc/4/

Comment: You know what the problem was- I had 'phone' in my JavaScript, but the id in my HTML file is 'telephone'.  It works now.  I really appreciate your help!  Can you please explain to me what the variables mean or how your code works out so I can understand this?  I would really like to learn this.  Thank you.

Comment: nothing special here, error variables(e.g. `nameError`) are just so you don't need to write `getElementById` twice and `else` sets error to empty if something is in input field

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called something like :

```
var fieldsInError = "";
```

Then in your validation in each check if it fails validation add the field:

```
fieldsInError += "name," (or whatever the field is)
```

Then at the end of the function update your error field with something like:

```
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please enter " + fieldsInError.substring(0, fieldsInError.length-1);
```

So your function would look something like this:

```
function validateForm() {
  var fieldsInError = "";
  var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
  if (name == "") {
    fieldsInError += "name,"
  }
  var email = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
  if (email == "") {
    fieldsInError += "email,"
  }

  var phone = document.forms["contactform"]["phone"].value;
  if (phone == "") {
    fieldsInError += "phone,"
  }

  if(fieldsInError != ""){
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please enter " + fieldsInError.substring(0, fieldsInError.length-1);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not make `fieldsInError` an array and `join(', ')` it?

Comment: I will try it out.  Does that mean I will have 7 lines of code?

Comment: @Marty I considered that but wanted to keep it as basic as possible.

Comment: @Simon, is there a way to just add something to my code above?  Another 'var ret = true;'?